# Syntax RDFa review Organization with multiple addresses

Tags: semantic-web, rdfa

I am having trouble figuring out the correct `rdfa` syntax for an aggregated review with multiple addresses and geolocations. I wish to make this available to the Google spider. The example below is what I have so far, but i am unsure whether this is correct. Also this only adds one address and geolocation and for most organisations we have multiple addresses (each with its own geo-location).

```html
<div xmlns:v="http://rdf.data-vocabulary.org/#" typeof="v:Review-aggregate">
 <span rel="v:itemreviewed">
    <span typeof="Organization">
     <span property="v:name">Company name</span>
     <span rel="v:address">
      <span typeof="v:Address">
       <span property="v:street-address">1 address</span>, 
       <span property="v:locality">City</span>, 
       <span property="v:postalCode">1234 AA</span>.
      </span>
     </span>
     <div property="location">
      <span typeof="Place">
       <span property="latitude" content="37.4149"></span>
       <span property="longitude" content="-122.078"></span>
      </span>
     </div>
    </span>
   <a href="http://www.example.com/" rel="v:url">website</a>
  <div style="clear:both"></div>
 </span >
 <span rel="v:rating">
  <span typeof="v:Rating">
   <span property="v:average" content="5"></span>
   <span property="v:best" content="10"></span>
   <span property="v:count" content="15"></span>
  </span>
 </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Would it make sense to review each location individually? Take for example the organization Apple. Each store location has different staff, a different building, and thus most likely people will rate them differently.

If you're looking at rating a Organization in general (Apple, Inc.), I would just use the headquaters address for the Organization as a whole, and not list all its stores under the same organization.

Comment: We rate organizations at a general level. So your suggestion about publishing the headquaters best fits our situation. Although i agree this seems the best method, i would like to know whether there is some official blog or article that confirms this.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use intended instruments like [Google Structured Validation Tool](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets)?

It gives pretty good result for your file

[image]

Comment: My question is more related to adding multiple addresses with multiple geo locations. The Google Structured Validation Tool does not provide information on how to do this. It 'only' validates the source. I can add multiple addresses and pass it through this tool and it seems ok, but that doesn't tell me if it is the best way.